# How do I create a search bar within a filemaker database?

Tags: filemaker

I create an attendance type database where I can scan student ID's and it will organize it by class and date they are attending.

Say for example I want to search a name from a specific date and class, instead of running through all the names, I want an efficient way to search for that particular student name from that particular class. Any suggestion to what I should do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want "*to search a name from a specific date and class*" then enter Find mode and enter the known name in the name field, the known date in the date field and the known class in the class field. Then perform find. Surely that's Filemaker basics?

Comment: @michael.hor257k I know that but I can't use the default find mode using the filemaker go app. I want to create my own search tool if thats possible

Comment: "*I can't use the default find mode using the filemaker go app.*" Why not? Of course, you *can* enter the search criteria into global fields in Browse mode, then script the find. Surely, that's Filemaker basics too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it sounds like there are two parts to what you're looking to do:

- Scan ID cards
- Perform a search for a particular ID based on the scan
- Performing a search for a name and date range

## Scanning the ID cards

This depends a bit on what device you're wanting to scan from and the type of barcodes you're scanning.

If you're creating an app that can run from FileMaker Go, you can scan barcodes by doing something like:

- Creating a text field to scan the barcodes into
- Create a button called **Scan**
- Creating a script for said button that uses the step `Insert from Device` that specifically inserts a barcode

  - You'll want to be sure that the barcode type that your IDs are using is in the list of accepted barcodes

When you're app is open in FileMaker Go and you tap on scan, go will bring up your iPhone's camera and allow you to scan a barcode. The barcode will then be scanned into the scan into the given field.

You can find a bit more on the various barcode types that Go uses [in this blog post](http://www.skeletonkey.com/using-barcodes-with-filemaker-go/).

If you're trying to scan from a desktop using FileMaker Pro, you'll need to look into purchasing a barcode scanner. As far as your computer is concerned, most scanners are just like a keyboard. when you scan a barcode, the scanner "types" those characters in.

In it's simplest form, you could:

- Click into the field that you want to scan the barcode into
- Scan the barcode with the barcode scanner

With barcode scanners you need to make sure that the one you purchase supports the barcodes you use. Some scanners only support inline barcodes, some support things like QR codes.

Whether you go with a Go solution on an iPhone or iPad or a barcode scanner solution on the desktop you'll need to figure out what kind of barcodes your IDs have.

If you're starting the entering of student data by scanning the id and then filling in the student information

## Performing a search with a barcode

Now that you know what you need to do to scan a barcode in, performing a find using a barcode is relatively simple.

All you need to do is create a script that puts you into find mode before you scan the barcode in. Your script could look something like this if you were using the FileMaker Go version:

- *Scan button is tapped*
- Enter Find Mode
- Insert from device [MyTable::MyIdField ; Barcode]
- Set Error Capture [On]
- Perform Find
- Set Variable [$error ; Get(lastError)]
- Set Error Capture [Off]
- If [ $error ]
- Show Custom Dialog Box ["The following error occurred during the search: "& $error]
- Endif

This would perform the search based on the barcode you scan in and show you an error message if nothing was found. If something was found you'd be on the record that matched the ID.

There are numerous ways you can do this kind of a process and plenty of details that you can add in, but at the very basic level you just need to get yourself ready to do a find, add the id from the barcode scanner, perform the find, and then handle the results.

## Performing a search for a name and date range

Now that we've talked about all of the barcode scanning and searching, searching for a name and date range is pretty straight forward.

The simplest thing to do would be to create a layout that has your name and date fields on it. Then you could enter Find Mode and enter the criteria you wanted to search for. For the name field you would type in a full or partial name that you wanted to find. If you were searching for a particular date range you could use the ellipses to define the range, e.g.:

```
1/2/2013...1/2/2015
```

This would find all records with a date between 1/2/2013 and 1/2/2015.

---

Is this closer to the answer you were looking for? If not add some more detail about what you're trying to do to the question.